# Loading data with Provider: Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, state-management, memory-efficient, loaddata

I am working on a Flutter App in which I want to load data using a REST API.
The provider class is as follows-
**CategoryProvider-**

```
class CategoryProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  SharedPreferences? sharedPreferences;
  late LoadingStatus loadingStatus;
  late CategoryService _categoryService;
  List<Category>? allCategories;
  CategoryProvider.initialze(SharedPreferences sf) {
    _initializePrefs(sf);
    loadingStatus = LoadingStatus.NOT_STARTED;
    _categoryService = CategoryService();
  }
  void _initializePrefs(SharedPreferences sf) {
    log('Initializing sharedPreferences');
    sharedPreferences = sf;
    log('Shared preference initialized');
  }

  void fetchAllCategories() async {
    allCategories = [];
    loadingStatus = LoadingStatus.LOADING;
    Map<String, dynamic> result = await _categoryService.fetchAllCategories(
        token: sharedPreferences!.getString(BEARER_TOKEN) ?? 'null');
    if (result['code'] == '2000') {
      allCategories = categoryFromJson(result['data']);
    } else {
      log('No categories: code: $result');
      allCategories = [];
    }
    loadingStatus = LoadingStatus.COMPLETED;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**UI Code-**

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final List<Widget> _pages = [
    PersonalFeedPage(),
    ExplorePage(),
    ProfilePage(),
    SettingsPage(),
  ];
  late PageController _pageController;
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _onTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
    _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
  }

  void onPageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final categoryProvider = Provider.of<CategoryProvider>(context);
    if (categoryProvider.loadingStatus == LoadingStatus.NOT_STARTED) {
      // log('Bottom Navigation: loading user for email: ${userProvider.sharedPreferences!.getString(EMAIL)} ');
      log("Bottom Navigation: fetching all categories");
      categoryProvider.fetchAllCategories();
    }
    return Scaffold(
      body: (!(categoryProvider.loadingStatus == LoadingStatus.LOADING ||
              categoryProvider.loadingStatus == LoadingStatus.NOT_STARTED))
          ? PageView(
              children: _pages,
              controller: _pageController,
              onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
            )
          : Center(
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                child: CustomLoadingIndicator(),
              ),
            ),
      bottomNavigationBar:
          (!(categoryProvider.loadingStatus == LoadingStatus.LOADING ||
                  categoryProvider.loadingStatus == LoadingStatus.NOT_STARTED))
              ? BottomNavigationBar(
                  currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
                  onTap: _onTapped,
                  items: [
                    const BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      label: "Feed",
                      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.rss),
                    ),
                    const BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      label: "Explore",
                      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.borderAll),
                    ),
                    const BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      label: "Profile",
                      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.user),
                    ),
                    const BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      label: "Settings",
                      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.gears),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              : null,
    );
  }
}
```

**What I want to do-**

- The **HomePage** consists of a **bottom navigation bar** which can be used to navigate between the **four pages**. **Home Page** is the first widget to be built when app is opened.
- Now, **when the app is opened**, I want to fetch all the data using the **fetchAllCategories()** method (which are stored in the **allCategories** variable).
- The same **fetchAllCategories() might be called from other parts of app to refresh data.**

**My approach-**

- I am using the **loadingStatus** variable in the **CategoryProvider** to keep track of the data loaded.
- If the data is getting loaded, it will be set as **LOADING**, else if not started fetching then as **NOT_STARTED** else if loaded then **COMPLETED**.
- The widgets will get built accordingly.

**My Question-**
I am fetching data in the **build()** method of the **Home Page** because I can't access context outside it. **So, will this approach be efficient in loading data or is there some more efficient approach for this functionality?** Although, this would work but I am not sure this is efficient and correct approach when I have to re-fetch the data?

Answer (score 0):

With ObjectBox instead of SharedPreferences you could read the data in sync. This would make the code a bit cleaner. I am using BLoC and with this package I would load the data in a quite different pattern. However, with ObjectBox you might be able to streamline your code such that it doesn't matter.

Comment: I am not using any local database for data persistence. I am only fetching data which would last only for app's runtime.